# Creating an object A with a ForeignKey to object B, when creating an object B

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

When creating posts in a text editor in the Django administration panel, I upload files. I want to link this file with the current post through a foreign key. The problem is that the post has not yet been created, but I need to refer to it.
My model:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    upload_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="uploaded_file_author")
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d/',)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="file_post")
```

My view:

```
@require_POST
def file_upload(request):
    reqfile = UploadFile.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'], upload_by=request.user, **post="need an object here")**
    return JsonResponse({'fileurl': reqfile.file.url})
```

My ajax request to upload files:

```
file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
    if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'MIME_type');

        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // FormData
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = file;
            fd.append("file",files);

            // AJAX
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/fileupload/file/",
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                async: true
            }).done(function(response){
                var location = response.fileurl;
                reader.onload = function(){
                    // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
                    cb(location, { download : files.name });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(files);
            });
        };
        input.click();
    }
}
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, UploadMedia, UploadFile, UploadImage
from .forms import MyTextForm
# Register your models here.


class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title", )}
    list_display = ["title", "updated", "created"]
    list_display_links = ["title"]
    list_filter = ["created", "tags"]
    search_fields = ["title", "content",]
    form = MyTextForm

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    class Media:
        js = ('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', 'js/csrf_setup.js',
              'js/tinymce/tinymce.js', 'js/init-tinymce.js',)


admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your POST is not created but you need to create UploadFile instance you can add null=True to post field.

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="file_post")
```

When you have post created you can link it to your upload_file instance by:

```
upload_file.post = Post.objects.create(...)
upload_file.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just either create

```
@require_POST
def file_upload(request):
    post = Post.objects.create(....)
    reqfile = UploadFile.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'], upload_by=request.user, post=post)
    return JsonResponse({'fileurl': reqfile.file.url})
```

Or retrieve a post instance and pass it to there:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@require_POST
def file_upload(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    reqfile = UploadFile.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'], upload_by=request.user, post=post)
    return JsonResponse({'fileurl': reqfile.file.url})
```

Comment: How to pass pk argument with Ajax request. I use an Ajax request to upload files.

Comment: In the template with template tags you can do this for example:{{query.pk}} this will give the pk of the instance passed to the template.

Comment: data: fd, this part data: {{query.pk}} but dont know how you are passing instanceto the templlace

Comment: Yes, the fact is that I create posts not on a separate page, but on the Django admin page. I don’t know yet where the admin page templates are located. I have not had such experience yet. I added my Ajax query to the bottom of the question.

Comment: So where do oyou plan do locate your ajax then?

Comment: If you had OneToOne field in the database you could filter according to the user by getting it from request like request.user but if you do this now you will get all the model instance which belongs to the user.

Comment: With media class in admin.py.